# vee validate import rules getting parmeter

Tags: vue.js, vee-validate

I want to get the min parameter on the error message for the following code

```js
extend('min', { ...min, message: 'The {_field_} field must have at least {_min_} characters'})
```

the `_min_` variable param is not returned when the field is not valid. How do i access that parameter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are facing two issues.

1. The minimum rule uses `length` rather than `min` as a parameter name ([reference](https://logaretm.github.io/vee-validate/guide/rules.html#min))
2. Parameter fields are not surrounded by underscores - as per [the documentation](https://logaretm.github.io/vee-validate/guide/basics.html#arguments-placeholders) - see below:

> One thing to note is that the parameter placeholder doesn't have underscores `_` around it unlike the `{_field_}` placeholder. This is a convention of vee-validate as there are special set of placeholders that have underscores around them. This is to prevent collisions and to make them distinct from rule parameters.

So for your code:

```
extend('min', { 
    ...min, 
    message: 'The {_field_} field must have at least {length} characters'
})
```

Comment: Works like a charm, Thanks @Rory